# sonata admin one-to-many and many-to-one display list

Tags: sonata-admin, symfony-sonata, sonata

I have a project about nurse and patients. Nurse goes around and visits patients. The problem that I'm facing is that the nurse wants to see a list of all the visits they did for a patient.

I do have two admin pages, one is the patients admin (allows to create/edit patients) and another one that allows to log visits. Within the visit you select the patient. From the patient list, how can I list all of the visits a nurse did for a patient? and further more, allow to click an add button to log a new visit.

I don't have code to show, but if any of you can point to some documentation, or sample code, will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

On the patient edit page you could do the following. Assuming your entity is called something like VisitLogs. You can add the following to configureFormFields

```
$formMapper->Add('VisitLogs', 'sonata_type_collection' ['type_options' => ['btn_add' => true]], ['inline' => 'table', 'edit' => 'inline']);
```

This should display a table with the Visitlogs based on the patients (if the ORM is correctly setup) and shows a add new button.

I hope this somewhat helps you a little bit further. [More information](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/reference/form_types.html#sonata-type-collection).

**Note** This is for the one-to-many relation. I'm guessing for the many-to-one relation you should use sonata_type_model not sure about that though.

Comment: If this is the answer you were looking for please mark it as answer, if not then I hope the link did help you out!